# modal show event is not firing

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have one view in asp.net MVC application, in which i have one table. on each row i have one anchor tag which will open modal window. I have written some code on modal show event. but the event is not firing. my view's layout is coming from custom layout page.following is the code for my view.

```
@Model
@Imports System.Data

@Code
    ViewBag.Title = ViewBag.Title
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLayout.vbhtml"
End Code

@Section js
    <script src="@Session("baseurl")/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Session("baseurl")/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Session("baseurl")/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
End Section

@section css

End Section
<script src="@Session("baseurl")/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="@Session("baseurl")/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="@Session("baseurl")/Styles/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Session("baseurl")/Styles/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Session("baseurl")/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<form action="@Session("baseurl")/ContainerList/List" method="post">
    <div class="row pl-md-1 pb-0">
        <div class="col-md-12 pl-1">
            <p class="lead" id="heading">@ViewBag.Heading</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <div class="alert alert-info form-control" id="infomsg">
                <label id="lblInfo" class="fa fa-info-circle">@Session("InfoMsg")</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 border border-primary pt-2 pb-2">
            <div class="row pb-3">
                <!--<div class="col-md-2 pt-1">
                    <label Class="col-form-label">@Session("ContainerNo")</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" name="containerno" id="containerno" class="form-control form-control-sm font-weight-bold text-uppercase" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>-->
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label Class="col-form-label">@Session("BOLNumber")</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="text" name="bolnumber" class="form-control form-control-sm font-weight-bold text-uppercase" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                @If Session("Lang") = "E" Then
                    @:<div Class="col-md-2 pr-0">
                Else
                    @:<div Class="col-md-2 pl-0">
                End If

                    <Label Class="col-form-label">@Session("FromRecvdDate")</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="inputWithIcon inputIconBg">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></i>
                        <input class="form-control form-control-sm font-weight-bold readonly" type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
                               name="fromrecvdate" id="fromrecvdate" style="width:100%" maxlength="12" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label Class="col-form-label">@Session("UptoRecvdDate")</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="inputWithIcon inputIconBg">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></i>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm font-weight-bold readonly" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
                               name="uptorecvdate" id="uptorecvdate" style="width:100%" maxlength="12" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row pt-3">
                @If Session("Lang") = "E" Then
                    @:<div Class="col-md-12 text-right">
                Else
                    @:<div Class="col-md-12 text-left">
                End If
                    <button type="submit" name="BtnCntList" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        @Session("BtnCntList")
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pt-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @If ViewBag.RowCount > 0 Then
                @:<table id="cntlist" class="table-responsive table table-bordered table-hover table-lightfont table-condensed">
                    @:<thead class="thead-light">
                        @:<th>@Session("tdcontainerno")</th>
                        @:<th>@Session("tdbolnumber")</th>
                        @:<th>@Session("tdarrivaldate")</th>
                        @:<th>@Session("tdrecvddate")</th>
                        @:<th>@Session("tdsku")</th>
                        @:<th>@Session("tdagent")</th>
                        @:<th>@Session("tdlot")</th>
                        @:<th>@Session("tdstatus")</th>
                        @:<th></th>
                    @:</thead>
                    @:<tbody>
                        @For Each row As System.Data.DataRow In Model.Rows

                            @:<tr>
                                For Each cell In row.ItemArray
                                    @:<td>@cell.ToString</td>
                                Next
                                @:<td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" title="@Session("MoreDetails")" data-target="#cntdetail" data-book_id='{"containerno":"@row.Item(0).ToString","lot":"@row.Item(6).ToString"}' class="btn"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i></a></td>
                            @:</tr>
                        Next

                    @:</tbody>
                @:</table>
            End If
        </div>
    </div>
```

following is the HTML code for modal

```
<div id="cntdetail" class="modal show fade" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h6>@Session("CntDetails")</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                   <input type="text" name="containerno" />
                    <input type="text" name="lot" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                        Close
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

following is the JavaScript for event firing for modal show

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $('#cntdetail').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
                alert("a");
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Kindly help somebody. I am stuck here since long time.

Comment: I tried this exact code on Bootstrap official website (by replacing modal id ofcourse.) I didn't find any issue the event fire successfully. Maybe there is some problem in where you placed your javascript code. Make sure you load your script code after jQuery and bootstrap js in the end of body section. and also remove show class from modal HTML it's not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try activating the modal via javascript using class instead of data-target.

```
$(".yourModalClassHere").click(() => {
    $('#cntdetail').modal('show');
})

$('#cntdetail').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    alert("a");
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. i have tried showing modal with click event but its not opening the modal. The event is firing but not showing modal. i checked by putting alert inside the code.

Comment: Hello @MAK, Did you remove that `show` class and tried? from `modal show fade`
also make sure that the click event is firing successfully by using console.log and if the `shown.bs.modal` event is firing then there must be some issue with modal visibility so please check by removing that `show` class. I hope this might help.